# SceneKit camera follow object only on x-axis? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, camera, scenekit

How can I move a camera according to the x position of a moving sphere, but ignore the y and z coordinates of that sphere at the same time? Here is my code for following the sphere on its 3 dimensions:

```
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.camera?.usesOrthographicProjection = true
    cameraNode.camera?.orthographicScale = 2
    let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: sphere)
    constraint.gimbalLockEnabled = true
    self.cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(20, 20, 20)
    cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0, 45, 0)
    sphere.addChildNode(cameraNode)
```

How can I just follow just the x position of the sphere, instead of it's  y and z positions as well?

Comment: Are you not able to access 'cameraNode.position.x' and assign a value directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un-child the camera from `sphere`, make it a child of `root` instead. Within whatever code is moving sphere, set the camera's x position to that of sphere.

```
// code moving sphere
cameraNode.position.x = sphere.position.x
```